# Close open div when new one is shown

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slide, uislider

Hi im very new to jq/js im using hide / show to open / close divs they work fine until I try to open a div when one is already open - they end up overlapping.

Is there a way to set it to close any open divs before opening a new one or perhaps only use hide if the div is open in the first place?

The jQuery I'm using is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.content').hide();

    $("#show-services").click(function () {
          $(".content#services").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });    


    $("#show-about").click(function () {
          $(".content#about").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });  


    $("#show-contact").click(function () {
          $(".content#contact").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });     

    $("#hide-services").click(function () {
          $(".content#services").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });

    $("#hide-about").click(function () {
          $(".content#about").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });

    $("#hide-contact").click(function () {
          $(".content#contact").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });

});
</script>
```

For reference the site its on is [www.pudle.co.uk/int](http://www.pudle.co.uk/int)  - you can see the conflict if you click a link in the top left and then click on another of the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using `show()`, use `hide()` on div(s) you want to hide something like:

```
$("#div1, #div2, #divX").hide(); // hide all these divs
$("#thisDiv").show(); // now show this one
```

Notice that you can combine multiple selectors with a comma like `$("#div1, #div2, #divX")`

Answer (score 1):

toggle could help : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

or something *like* this :

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $(".content").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); //hide them all
    $(".content#"+this.id).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);//show one
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your content divs have a class of 'content', simply hide all of the divs with a class of content before showing the current one.

```
$("#show-services").click(function () {
    $('.content').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    $(".content#services").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll find the :visible selector very useful for this.
Example

```
$("#show-services").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); // this is for the URL to not change.
      $(".content:visible .hide a").click(); // you get the visible first div in .content and make a click on the HIDE link
      $(".content#services").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

});
```

A good and easy Jquery reference can be found in http://visualjquery.com/ go to selectors :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write so many click handlers.
In the anchor specify the corresponding div eg: href="#services"

```
$("#links a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   whichdiv = $(this).attr("href");
   $('.content').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
   $(whichdiv).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
})
```